# create rest-full login API in that i want to generate jwt token valid for certain time only

Tags: php, codeigniter, jwt

Libraries code I get from https://github.com/b3457m0d3/JWT-CodeIgniter
and I have to create login API in that i want to generate  token valid for certain time only.
**comtroller

```
<?php
require APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php';
class Comx extends REST_Controller 
{ 
    public function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('session');
         $this->load->helper('cookie');

    $this->load->library('jwt');

    }
     public  function  generate_token($user_id)
    {
      //$this->load->library("jwt");
   $CONSUMER_KEY = '124578';
        $CONSUMER_SECRET = '456123';
        $CONSUMER_TTL = 60;
        var_dump( $this->jwt->encode(array(
          'consumerKey'=>$CONSUMER_KEY,
      'userId'=>$user_id,
          'issuedAt'=>date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime("now")),
          'ttl'=>$CONSUMER_TTL
        ), $CONSUMER_SECRET));
    }

  **
```

> // application/ libraries/jwt.php but this code give me error on line 89 of controller Undefined property: Comx::$JWT ?is it can not load library

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * JSON Web Token implementation
 *
 * Minimum implementation used by Realtime auth, based on this spec:
 * http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-jones-json-web-token-01.html.
 *
 * @author Neuman Vong <neuman@twilio.com>
 * @minor changes for codeigniter <b3457m0d3@interr0bang.net>
 */
class JWT
{
    /**
     * @param string      $jwt    The JWT
     * @param string|null $key    The secret key
     * @param bool        $verify Don't skip verification process 
     *
     * @return object The JWT's payload as a PHP object
     */
    public function decode($jwt, $key = null, $verify = true)
    {
        $tks = explode('.', $jwt);
        if (count($tks) != 3) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Wrong number of segments');
        }
        list($headb64, $payloadb64, $cryptob64) = $tks;
        if (null === ($header = $this->jsonDecode($this->urlsafeB64Decode($headb64)))
        ) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Invalid segment encoding');
        }
        if (null === $payload = $this->jsonDecode($this->urlsafeB64Decode($payloadb64))
        ) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Invalid segment encoding');
        }
        $sig = $this->urlsafeB64Decode($cryptob64);
        if ($verify) {
            if (empty($header->alg)) {
                throw new DomainException('Empty algorithm');
            }
            if ($sig != $this->sign("$headb64.$payloadb64", $key, $header->alg)) {
                throw new UnexpectedValueException('Signature verification failed');
            }
        }
        return $payload;
    }
    /**
     * @param object|array $payload PHP object or array
     * @param string       $key     The secret key
     * @param string       $algo    The signing algorithm
     *
     * @return string A JWT
     */
    public function encode($payload, $key, $algo = 'HS256')
    {
        $header = array('typ' => 'jwt', 'alg' => $algo);
        $segments = array();
        $segments[] = $this->urlsafeB64Encode($this->jsonEncode($header));
        $segments[] = $this->urlsafeB64Encode($this->jsonEncode($payload));
        $signing_input = implode('.', $segments);
        $signature = $this->sign($signing_input, $key, $algo);
        $segments[] = $this->urlsafeB64Encode($signature);
        return implode('.', $segments);
    }
    /**
     * @param string $msg    The message to sign
     * @param string $key    The secret key
     * @param string $method The signing algorithm
     *
     * @return string An encrypted message
     */
    public function sign($msg, $key, $method = 'HS256')
    {
        $methods = array(
            'HS256' => 'sha256',
            'HS384' => 'sha384',
            'HS512' => 'sha512',
        );
        if (empty($methods[$method])) {
            throw new DomainException('Algorithm not supported');
        }
        return hash_hmac($methods[$method], $msg, $key, true);
    }
    /**
     * @param string $input JSON string
     *
     * @return object Object representation of JSON string
     */
    public function jsonDecode($input)
    {
        $obj = json_decode($input);
        if (function_exists('json_last_error') && $errno = json_last_error()) {
            $this->handleJsonError($errno);
        }
        else if ($obj === null && $input !== 'null') {
            throw new DomainException('Null result with non-null input');
        }
        return $obj;
    }
    /**
     * @param object|array $input A PHP object or array
     *
     * @return string JSON representation of the PHP object or array
     */
    public function jsonEncode($input)
    {
        $json = json_encode($input);
        if (function_exists('json_last_error') && $errno = json_last_error()) {
            $this->handleJsonError($errno);
        }
        else if ($json === 'null' && $input !== null) {
            throw new DomainException('Null result with non-null input');
        }
        return $json;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $input A base64 encoded string
     *
     * @return string A decoded string
     */
    public function urlsafeB64Decode($input)
    {
        $remainder = strlen($input) % 4;
        if ($remainder) {
            $padlen = 4 - $remainder;
            $input .= str_repeat('=', $padlen);
        }
        return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
    }
    /**
     * @param string $input Anything really
     *
     * @return string The base64 encode of what you passed in
     */
    public function urlsafeB64Encode($input)
    {
        return str_replace('=', '', strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/', '-_'));
    }
    /**
     * @param int $errno An error number from json_last_error()
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function handleJsonError($errno)
    {
        $messages = array(
            JSON_ERROR_DEPTH => 'Maximum stack depth exceeded',
            JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR => 'Unexpected control character found',
            JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX => 'Syntax error, malformed JSON'
        );
        throw new DomainException(isset($messages[$errno])
            ? $messages[$errno]
            : 'Unknown JSON error: ' . $errno
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am assuming that you are including this library to prevent CSRF attacks. If that is your only aim then you can very easily implement random tokens in yours forms by using CodeIgniter security classes. visit https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html for more information.

Comment: what i understand that CodeIgniter security classes is that it save token in cookie .is using cookie is god for rest api as cookies are associated with browser but one can use it for different  platforms?